# Bash: Killing all screens with a specified name

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

If I have multiple screens with the same name, how could I kill all of them without checking all of their PIDs, and then executing `screen -wipe`?

Example:

```
24754.screen1  (Detached)
32236.screen1  (Detached)
7308.screen1   (Detached)
3896.screen1   (Detached)
10155.screen1  (Detached)
10888.screen1  (Detached)
28438.screen1  (Detached)
26008.screen1  (Detached)
```

I would like to kill all instances of screen1, terminate any processes running within, and not need to run `screen -wipe` after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if clean enough. The -X quit operation shall not need a -wipe:

```
screen -ls | awk -vFS='\t|[.]' '/screen1/ {system("screen -S "$2" -X quit")}'
```

You should able to dive into each shell your session started and send an exit in theory

Comment: I meant more graceful, send every shell session in a screen session an exit and thus shell exit inside itself. The -X quit operation will rely on screen to close it's children process